# SQLite Update Syntax for string concatenation?

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax, string-concatenation

I have a table with this data

```
id , name    , description
1  , apple   , ''
2  , orange  , ''
```

I am trying to pass the following statement to update the row so the description column is 'desc of apple' and 'desc of orange' but it is not working.

```
 Update TestTable Set description = 'desc of ' + name
```

What is the proper syntax to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

SQLite's [string concatenation operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) is "`||`", not "`+`"

```
UPDATE TestTable SET description = 'desc of ' || name;
```

Comment: + is not standard SQL syntax for string concatenation.

Comment: Is there a standard SQL Syntax for string concatenation?  It seems every DB uses a different one.  MySQL Uses Concat() function, SQL Lite using ||, SQL Server Uses +.  Definitely something that should be standardized.

Comment: Yes, there is a standard SQL syntax. It is `||`, [adopted](https://books.google.com/books?id=6jqZExL6UGcC&pg=PA106&dq=concatenation+infixed+operator&hl=en&sa=X#v=onepage) in the [SQL-92 standard  ISO/IEC 9075:1992](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1920&bih=979&q=%22concatenation+operator%22+ISO%2FIEC+9075:1992+X3H2-92-154+%22double+period%22).
It's just that SQL Server and MySQL chose not to comply with the standard. Although MySQL can be coaxed by setting [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat)